# Question about the $\mathrm{Tor}$ functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Assume we want to define $\mathrm{Tor}_n (M,N)$ where $M,N$ are $R$-modules and $R$ is a commutative unital ring.

We take a projective resolution of $M$:

$$ \dots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0$$

Now does it matter whether we apply $-\otimes N$ or $N \otimes -$ to this? It shouldn't because we have $N \otimes P \cong P \otimes N$. Right? Thanks.

Comment: $R$ is commutative?

Comment: Well, $M$ is a right module and $N$ is a left module.

Comment: Yes, $R$ is commutative.

Comment: @ehsanmo The question is tagged `[commutative-algebra]`....

Comment: @BenjaLim That tag was added in response to the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the point here is that $N \otimes_R -$ and $- \otimes_R N$ are naturally isomorphic functors. Therefore, you get an isomorphism of *chain complexes* $N \otimes_R P^{\bullet} \cong P^{\bullet} \otimes_R N$, which implies that the two complexes have isomorphic homology. So, it doesn't matter if you apply $N \otimes_R -$ or $- \otimes_R N$.

Comment: Do you mean homology? The $\mathrm{Tor}$ functor is the homology of the resulting long exact sequence.

Comment: As you use chain complexes (as opposed to cochain complexes), it should indeed be homology instead of cohomology. I'll edit my answer accordingly.